# How to include Vref in thermistor temperature calculation?

Tags: programming, c++, thermistor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2H0XB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the code that I'm using to get the temperature:

```
#define COEFF_A 0.8662984364E-03
#define COEFF_B 2.780704551E-04
#define COEFF_C -0.9395108479E-07

float VRT, Temp;
float Vref = 2.52;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);
}

void loop() {
  long Resistance;
  VRT = analogRead(A3);
  Resistance = 10000 / ((1023.0 / VRT) - 1);
  Temp = log(Resistance);
  Temp = 1 / (COEFF_A + (COEFF_B * Temp) + (COEFF_C * pow(Temp, 3)));
  Temp += -273.15;
  Serial.println(Temp);
  delay(500);
}
```

I know that the calculation should be: `V = Vref × VRT ÷ 1023` but i don't know how to implant it in this code, any help appreciated.

---

## Update

After Edgar Bonet [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/68288/57281), the edited code is:

```
#define COEFF_A 0.8662984364E-03
#define COEFF_B 2.780704551E-04
#define COEFF_C -0.9395108479E-07

float VRT, Temp, VR;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);
}

void loop() {
  long Resistance;
  VRT = analogRead(A3);
  VR = 2.52 * VRT / 1024;
  Resistance = 10000 * VR / (2.52 - VR);
  Temp = log(Resistance);
  Temp = 1 / (COEFF_A + (COEFF_B * Temp) + (COEFF_C * pow(Temp, 3)));
  Temp += -273.15;
  Serial.println(Temp);
  delay(500);
}
```

But the temperature reading is 2 centigrade less than what it should be, when i remove the `analogReference(EXTERNAL);` it shows the normal/correct temperature readings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula to get the analog voltage from the ADC reading is:

V = V<sub>ref</sub> × reading ÷ 1024

(yes, it's 1024, not 1023). The formula to get the thermistor resistance
from the measured voltage is:

R = R<sub>ref</sub> × V ÷ (V<sub>ref</sub> − V)

where R<sub>ref</sub> is your 10 kΩ pull-up. You can combine these
two formulas in order to get the resistance directly from the ADC
reading:

R = R<sub>ref</sub> × reading ÷ (1024 − reading)

You may notice that, while doing this simplification, V<sub>ref</sub>
cancels out. It's not an error. The readings you get with this setup are
indeed independent of your reference voltage.

---

**Update 1**: After the OP's edit, we now have a *completely different*
question. The question is now: how come the readings do depend on the
reference voltage that is used, whereas in theory they should not.

The answer lies most likely in the ADC calibration. If high accuracy is
a requirement, the correct formula for the measured voltage is

V = V<sub>ref</sub> ×
(reading + E<sub>off</sub>) ÷ (1024 + E<sub>gain</sub>)

where E<sub>off</sub> and E<sub>gain</sub> are the offset error and the
gain error respectively. These errors are not knows *a priori*, and they
are usually neglected when the accuracy requirement is low. The
datasheet only gives constraints on how big these errors can be. The
actual values depend on the specific microcontroller and can somewhat
depend on the reference voltage. The only solution to get rid of these
errors is to calibrate your own ADC. See [Response of the Arduino
ADC](https://wiki.logre.eu/index.php/R%C3%A9ponse_de_l%27ADC_d%27un_Arduino/en) for an example on how this could be done.

---

**Update 2**: If I had to program this in an Arduino, I would rather
simplify the calculations as much as possible before coding:

- do *not* compute the measured analog voltage, nor the resistance, as
  they are not needed
- compute instead the ratio R/R<sub>ref</sub> directly from the analog
  reading
- rewrite the calibration polynomial as a function of
  log(R/R<sub>ref</sub>) instead of log(R) (which actually means
  log(R/(1 Ω)))
- optimize the evaluation of the polynomial by using
  [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

With these optimizations, we get:

```cpp
// Coefficients of polynomial fit of log(R/Rref) -> 1/T.
const float c0 = 3.3540165e-3;
const float c1 = 2.5416075e-4;
const float c2 = -2.5959644e-6;
const float c3 = -9.3951087e-8;

// Convert ADC reading to temperature in deg. C.
static float temperature(int reading)
{
    float R_ratio = reading / (1024.0 - reading);  // = R / Rref
    float x = log(R_ratio);
    float inverse_T = c0 + x*(c1 + x*(c2 + x*c3));
    return 1/inverse_T - 273.15;
}

void loop()
{
    int reading = analogRead(A3);
    Serial.println(temperature(reading));
    deay(500);
}
```

Comment: so in this example it should be this: `Resistance = 2.52 * VRT / (1024 - VRT);`, correct?

Comment: No. Your reference resistance is 10 kΩ, not 2.52 Ω.

Comment: but the readings is wrong, `Resistance = 10000 * VRT / (1024 - VRT);` did i missed something? it's like 2C less...

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Please, edit your original question if there is something missing.

Comment: when i use your suggested formula `Resistance = 10000 * VRT / (1024 - VRT);` the temperature is 2 centigrade less than what it should be.

Comment: unless i remove the `analogReference(EXTERNAL);`, that means it don't ignore "cancel" the Vref!

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: The article you linked is a piece of gold, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I formulated this answer on your previous, deleted question.

Whether the voltage increases or decreases with rising temperature depends on your circuit: if you use the ntc with R1 as a pull-down, the voltage will increase on rising temperature. If R1 is a pullup the voltage will fall respectively.

Concerning your calculation: I highly recommend using a look-up table instead. Those are some hard calculations, and at the arduinos resolution you'll be fine with a LUT with about 64 entries. There're tools out there which generate LUTs for a given NTC setup (I personally like [this tool](http://www.sebulli.com/ntc/index.php?lang=en)).

Comment: uh i feel so bad now that i deleted that question while you was answering it! sorry...

Comment: the code that i posted in my question does all the calculations, i don't need to re-do it, i just need to add the Vref into the calculation and don't know how... it's a pull-down btw.